# Opencart how to add product options into a tab

Tags: opencart

Opencart 1.5.3. Im trying to get the product options on the page to be displayed inside a tab. If I use the following code I get no errors and it looks fine, but clicking add to cart does nothing. If the code is outside the tab it works fine. Im not sure what Im doing wrong.

```
<div id="tabs_container">
<ul id="tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab4">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="tabs_content_container">
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="display:block"></div><!--tab1-->
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content"></div><!--tab2-->
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content"></div><!--tab3-->
<div id="tab4" class="tab_content">

<?php if ($options) { ?>
      <div class="options">
        <h2><?php echo $text_option; ?></h2>
        <br />
        <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
        <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
        <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
          <?php if ($option['required']) { ?>
          <span class="required">*</span>
          <?php } ?>
          <b><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</b><br />
          <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
            <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
            <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
            (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
            <?php } ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>

</div><!--tab4-->
</div><!--tabs_content_container-->
```

Here is the javascript for the form submit that Opencart uses.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

                if (json['error']) {
                    if (json['error']['option']) {
                        for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                            $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                        }
                    }
                } 

                if (json['success']) {
                    $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                    $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
                }   
            }
        });
    });
    //--></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be that the closing `</form>` tag won't be around the tab content. You need to move the `</form>` after your content and that should do it

Comment: I was thinking about the form tags too and realized Opencart seems to use javascript and binds the submit button. I edited my original post with the javascript code.

Comment: Have you tried moving the form tag though? Also note that they need to be in a wrapper element with the .product-info class too

Comment: Ive moved the javascript bind function that I posted above, but it doesnt seem to matter where you put it, so I just leave at the end of the page. I think youre onto something about the .product-info class that is written in the javascript. Im going to check those divs

Comment: Jay I have it working now. I decided to change .product-info in the javascript to my content wrapper and working perfect now.